# loading screen with delay in javascript

Tags: javascript, loading, setinterval

I need to create a loading screen (i want it in javascript), but i create a gif animate with the logo of the company and the loading screen disappaer too fast.

```
 window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    var load_screen = document.getElementById("load_screen");
    document.body.removeChild(load_screen); }); 
window.onload = function () {setTimeout(pippo(), 3000)}
function pippo(){
    document.getElementById(load_screen).style.display = 'none';
}
```

load_screen is the id of the div with the animated gif I want show.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    setInterval(pippo, 3000);   
});
function pippo(){
    var load_screen = document.getElementById("load_screen");
    document.body.removeChild(load_screen);
}
```

problem solved :)
this code work, but if exist a new or better method, you're welcome to suggest